# Wrong calculation of the knot group of a trefoil

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

I wonder what is wrong in the following calculation of the fundamental group of the complement in $\mathbb R^3$ of the trefoil knot:

[image: Trefoil knot]

Blue lines are the boundaries of two open opposite overlaping semispaces, which divide the complement of the knot into two open sets $U$ and $V$. Then $U\cap V$ is homotopic to $\mathbb R^2$ minus four points, and hence $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ is a rank $4$ free group.

On the other hand, $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic to open balls minus two lines joining two pair of points of the boundary, which are homotopic to open discs minus two points. So $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$ are rank $2$ free groups.

Now, the map $\pi_1(U\cap V)\longrightarrow \pi_1(U)$ identifies the four generators in pairs, as well as $\pi_1(U\cap V)\longrightarrow \pi_1(U)$ does, but the identified pairs are different in each case.

Applying van Kampen's theorem, $\pi_1(U\cup V)$ is the amalgamated sum of $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$, in which all four generators become identified. Hence $\pi_1(U\cup V)\cong \mathbb Z$.

This is false, of course, but, what is wrong in the above "proof"?

Comment: I haven't read the computation, but since this has happened to me before, I am sure I know what's going on: You're not being careful about basepoints, so that something that should really look like a conjugate of a generator looks like a generator. The reason that you get $\Bbb Z$ in the end is that the computation you are secretly doing is a homology computation.

Comment: You are right. This is just what I needed. Thank you!